# In SAS how do I group my ratios into high medium and low?

Tags: sas

I calculate a ratio for 40 stocks. I need to sort those into three groups high, medium and low based on the value of the ratio.  The ratios are fractions of one and there aren't many repetitions. What I need is to create three groups of about 13 stocks each, in group 1 to have the high ratios, in group 2 medium ratios and group 3 low ratios. I have the below code but it just assigns rank 1 to all my stocks.
How can I correct this?

```
data sourceh.combinedfreq2;
merge sourceh.nonnfreq2 sourceh.nofreq2 sourcet.caps;
by symbol;
ratio=(freqnn/freq);
run;

proc rank data=sourceh.combinedFreq2 out=sourceh.ranked groups=3;
by symbol notsorted;
var ratio;
ranks rank;
run;
```

Comment: How are you defining the three groups - what do you consider high/medium/low, or how do you want to define those if that's part of the question?

Comment: Yep- remove `by` line from the proc rank, and it should work.  `rank` should now have 0/1/2 based on ranks.  Rename that to whatever you want of course (`ranks <varname>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automatically partition into three relatively even groups, you can use PROC RANK (See example using sashelp.stocks):

```
data have;
set sashelp.stocks;
ratio=high/low;
run;

proc rank data=have out=want groups=3;
by stock notsorted;
var ratio;
ranks rank;
run;
```

That partitions them into three groups.  As long as you have 40 different values (ie, not a lot of repeats of one value), it will make 3 evenly split groups (with ~13 in each).

In your case, do not use `by` anything - `by` will create separate sets of ranks (here I'm ranking dates by stock, but you want to rank stocks.)

Comment: Somehow this didn't work. It changed all my ratios to 1. The ratios are fractions of one and there aren't many repetitions. What I need is to create three groups of about 13 stocks each, in group 1 to have the high ratios, in group 2 medium ratios and group 3 low ratios. Thank you.

Comment: Also - please edit that information into the original question.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my program (and the original question) with your suggested code. However, now it just creates a variable titled rank and assigns 1 to all the stocks. Do you know where I may be going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you take the `by` out?  `by` isn't appropriate for your data at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think people are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Lets do this on easy mode.

First, we'll create the dataset and create out ratios.
Second, We'll sort the data by ratio.
Lastly, we'll assign a group based on observation number.

WARNING! UNTESTED CODE!

```
/*Make the dataset. I stole this from your code above*/
data sourceh.combinedfreq2;
merge sourceh.nonnfreq2 sourceh.nofreq2 sourcet.caps;
by symbol;
ratio=(freqnn/freq);
run;

/*sort the data so that its ordered by ratio*/
PROC SORT DATA=sourceh.combinedfreq2 OUT=sourceh.combinedfreq2 ;
BY DESCENDING ratio ;
RUN ;

/*Assign a value based on observation number*/
Data sourceh.combinedfreq2;
Set sourceh.combinedfreq2;

length Group $6.;

if _N_ <=13 Then Group = "High";
if _N_ > 13 and _N_ <= 26 Then Group = "Medium";
if _N_ > 26 Then Group = "Low";

run;
```